# Use a workflow to set permissions

Tags: permissions, designer-workflow

Is it possible to create a reusable workflow that sets permissions?
I want to create a workflow that can be used when i create a site using a certain template. The template doesnt save unique permissions and i was wondering if you could create a workflow that did this instead.